# Add input box (e.g. AutoCompleteBox) to Application Bar

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, application-bar

How can I add controls like the AutoCompleteBox from Silverlight Toolkit to the Application Bar? I would like to create an Application Bar similar to the one in Internet Explorer app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can do that using the default ApplicationBar. However, you may create your own user Control and make it function like the existing ApplicationBar. Hope it helps.